# Spring Boot [2.7.1] is not compatible with this Spring Cloud release train

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-contract

Getting below error while using **Springboot 2.7.1** with **spring-cloud-version 2021.0.3** and **Spring contract is 3.1.3**

It is gradle project and using below configuration:-

- ("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-contract-gradle-plugin:3.1.3")
- ("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies2021.0.3")

```
        Caused by:
        org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'compositeCompatibilityVerifier' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/configuration/CompatibilityVerifierAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cloud.configuration.CompositeCompatibilityVerifier]: Factory method 'compositeCompatibilityVerifier' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.cloud.configuration.CompatibilityNotMetException: Spring Cloud/ Spring Boot version compatibility checks have failed: [[VerificationResult@46639e39 description = 'Spring Boot [2.7.1] is not compatible with this Spring Cloud release train', action = 'Change Spring Boot version to one of the following versions [2.6.x] .
        You can find the latest Spring Boot versions here [https://spring.io/projects/spring-boot#learn]. 
        If you want to learn more about the Spring Cloud Release train compatibility, you can visit this page [https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud#overview] and check the [Release Trains] section.
        If you want to disable this check, just set the property [spring.cloud.compatibility-verifier.enabled=false]']]
            at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:658)
            at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:638)
            at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352)
            at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195)
            at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582)
            at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
            at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
            at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
            at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
            at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
            at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:955)
            at app//org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
            at app//org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
            at app//org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734)
            at app//org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408)
            at app//org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308)
            at app//org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:132)
            at app//org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
            at app//org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
            ... 86 more
```

Comment: I'll take a look. That shouldn't happen.

Comment: I created a sample project from https://start.spring.io and the above error did not occur. The required version of spring-cloud-commons is 3.1.3. What version of spring-cloud-commons do you have. You can check with `./gradlew dependencies`

Comment: It is `org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-commons:3.1.3` and getting resolved :-

`
 org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:2021.0.3 -- > org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-commons:3.1.3 (c)

`

Comment: You couldn't get that error then. I'd need a sample application that reproduces the error

Comment: It got resolved, actually inside the we were setting "cloud.compatibility-verifier.      compatible-boot-versions" property to 2.6.x, and due to which it was no finding the 2.7.x version.

Comment: You should never need to set that property

Comment: Yes, We have just removed it.